# How to make a limit for tries in c++?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to make a limit for a program where if you keep answering the wrong question the program shuts down. How do I do this? I've tried adding a limit to a loop where once the limit ends *if* the loop exceeds the limit then I should end. I've also tried to turn the error message into a string variable and counting and adding a limit to how many times it can be printed. How do I fix this? Here's the code:

```
std::cout << error; // error is the error message

cin.clear();

cin.ignore(123, '\n');

std::cin >> units;
```

Comment: Can you show us more of your code?  Where's the retry loop?  The first attempt to read `units` before you realised there was an error?  What's the type of `units`?  On this site, it's expected that you'll post a compilable, minimal program that can reproduce your actual problems.

Answer (score 3):

One simple solution could be a `while` loop with a counter;

```
int tries = 3;
while (tries--) {
    // Other code
}
```

This will run the "other code" until `tries` reaches `0`, and `tries` is decremented each time you go round the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice using a counter. Whenever the user inputs a wrong answer the counter should increase. As long as the counter would be smaller than your limit of choice user input can continue. When:`counter == someLimit`, you can provide some output to let the user know he rached the limit and stop the execution.